# gnu parallel remove escape before space characters in command

Tags: command-line, bash, gnu-parallel

I'm currently testing gnu parallel to distribute a compare command across multiple servers using bash. In its most basic function this compare command takes two inputs to compare (oracle database accessions) and requires an output filename via -o. At least one action load, save, or direct upload is required by the program.

```
compare -o cmp.input1.input2.dat Input1 Input2
```

I have a few thousand of these input pairs and create a file with all the combinations so that each line contains the output filename and the database identifiers required by the program

```
#test_parallel
-o cmp.input1.input2.dat Input1 Input2
-o cmp.input1.input3.dat Input1 Input3
-o cmp.input2.input3.dat Input2 Input3
[...]
```

and execute the command using parallel, however the compare command fails

```
parallel -a test_parallel "compare {}"
ERROR: No action specified for results (load, save or direct upload)
usage: compare [-u][-o <file>] query target
```

using `--dryrun` mode this is what parallel executes:

```
compare -o\ cmp.input1.input2.dat\ Input1\ Input2
```

For some reason I don't understand, the escaped white space is not handled correctly by the compare program. Executing this command in bash results in the exact same error message message. Removing the escape after the -o flag (I could move the -o to the parallel command) results in a "too many arguments" error. Removing all escapes executes the command as expected.

Is it possible to tell parallel to not print the escape on the command call? I don't seem to find anything in the documentation, except that this is the expected default behavior, as indicated by `parallel --shellquote`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GNU Parallel treats input as a single argument and quotes it so you can safely use filenames like:

```
My brother's 12" records costs 30$ each.txt
```

In your case you want the argument to be parsed by the shell, so the spaces will be unquoted:

```
parallel -a test_parallel eval compare {}
```

Or you can split on space:

```
parallel --colsep ' ' -a test_parallel compare {1} {2} {3} {4}
```

But since you want to compare all vs. all you can do it much more elegantly:

```
parallel cmp -o ../out/cmp.{1}.{2} {1} {2} ::: Input* ::: Input*
```

This will compare all Input* to all Input*. With `--results` you can get the outputs nicely structured in a dir:

```
parallel --results out/ cmp {1} {2} ::: Input* ::: Input*
```

But if you want to skip running `cmp InputY InputX` after you already ran `cmd InputX InputY` then you can do this:

```
parallel --results out/ cmp {=1' $arg[1] ge $arg[2] and $job->skip();' =} {2} ::: Input* ::: Input*
```

Edit:

Version 20190722 introduces the function `uq`.

```
parallel -a test_parallel compare {=uq=}
```

`uq` is a perl function. When called, GNU Parallel will refrain from quoting that replacement string. So you can mix quoted and unquoted replacement strings:

```
parallel echo {} = {=uq=} ::: \$PWD
# You can change $_ if you want: uq() is a normal perl function
parallel echo {}ME = '{=uq(); $_.="ME"=}' ::: \$HO \$LOGNA
```

Comment: Thank you Ole, the combination with `eval` is just what I needed. The split on space probably won't work because the number of arguments changes depending on the input. The compare program I use does a comparison of biological sequences and reports the closest matches, a very special use case.

Comment: @Ole Tange is there a simple flag that would disable all 'automated quotings' by parallel? Just one argument. That's it? I am looking at all those manipulations with evals and uq and my head is spinning. So complicated.

Comment: @Andrew You are in luck: Since the answer was written GNU Parallel has added `uq`. With that you can mix quoted and non-quoted: `parallel echo {} = {=uq=} ::: \$PWD`.

Comment: @OleTange How to use uq? Why is it surrounded by equal signs? Curly braces? What is that? I have no idea how to use it. Can't it be just --disable-quotes or something like that and that's it?

Comment: @andrew {= perl replacement strings =} are covered in 5.2.3 (https://zenodo.org/record/1146014) and mentioned on the cheatsheet (https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_cheat.pdf) and in man parallel (search for \{= ). See also the example in the edit above. The reason for not just adding an extra option is that you get the flexibility that you can have one replacement string quoted and another unquoted in the same command template. You will mostly simply be using {=uq=}.

Comment: @OleTange Why would you ever want one to be escaped and another not? You definitely use some other scripting language to build command anyway... Seems too much confusion for too little gain. I use curl, how do I ask it to not escape multiple request headers from a config file?

Comment: If you want to do: `parallel echo {} = {=uq=} ::: \$PWD`. Also: It is implemented, where as --disable-quotes is not.